# How do i call vim in my shell script to open with a file name that I've put in?

Tags: shell, vim, terminal

I'm writing this shell script to help me automate a few things.
I basically input a file name, which my script reads and then commands vim to create and open an empty file( in the name i've just typed in), in which i'll type some info, according to what the file should contain. I'll then save and the script will go ahead to write necessary permissions to this file, the push it to a repository.
However, vim opens but with an empty filename and yet i need it to open with the name that i give to the script. what am i missing here?

below is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "file_name"
read $name
vi $name
chmod 755 *[!README.md]
git add $name
git commit -m '$varname'
git push
```

Comment: Learn to use https://shellcheck.net before you post your questions here (-; . If you still are having trouble **after** using shellcheck, then be sure to use the shellcheck corrected code in the body of your question and add a note "I have used shellcheck on this code" (or similar). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

`read` expects the name of the variable:

```
read name
```

You invoke it as

```
read $name
```

The shell processes the variable substitution. If `$name` is not set, you just invoke `read`, which stores your answer into `$REPLY`; if `$name` was, e.g. `"George"`, then you are reading into the variable `$George`.

Comment: And shellcheck will mention at least one other good practice to include. Good luck to all.